# split file lines into array and then parse into dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to read a file. I want to parse the lines of the file as a dictionary, but I can't seem to get that part into my array.

My file looks like:

**Records:**

```
2014-05-14,12:16:26,subject,{MSGTYPE="Personal" NAME="Fred" ADDRESS="Flat1" AGE=92 GENDER="M"}

2014-05-15,14:36:26,subject,{MSGTYPE="Personal" NAME="George" ADDRESS="Flat2"       AGE=-20 GENDER="M"}

2014-05-13,16:49:26,subject,{MSGTYPE="Personal" NAME="Ringo" ADDRESS="Flat3"    AGE=-36 GENDER="M"}

2014-05-12,14:45:26,subject,{MSGTYPE="Personal" NAME="Brian" ADDRESS="Flat4" AGE=-85 GENDER="M"}

2014-05-11,12:43:26,subject,{MSGTYPE="Personal" NAME="Paul" ADDRESS="Flat5" AGE=-33 GENDER="M"}
```

So the plan is to split it by ','. Then take value 4 and place it into its own dictionary. BUT I'm doing something wrong with the split.

```
valuesArray = []
f = open(rvfile)
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('**Records**'):
            valuesArray = line.split(',')
            print '1: {0}'.format(valuesArray[0])
            print '2: {1}'.format(valuesArray[1])
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "FAST_RV_Tests.py", line 70, in <module>
IndexError: index out of range: 1
```

The first print is returning '1: 2014-05-14' as I'd expect. But there is nothing else in the array.

Comment: It seems that there is nothing in the right part of the symbol ',' for that line

Comment: These records are not JSON so you are going to have to parse it yourself in order to turn it in to JSON.

Comment: Also your code is not indented correctly so it is not valid Python, and you should use the `with` keyword to open the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely to have empty lines in your data file, and splitting such line will not return list with enough items present.

In your loop you shall call `continue` if you meet an empty line.

Another hint is to call `split` with 2nd argument telling, how many splits shall be applied. This shall allow getting the final JSON part and you may use `json.loads` on it to get the content

If I modify your data to reflect your statement about having JSON data at the end,

```
014-05-14,12:16:26,subject,{"MSGTYPE":"Personal", "NAME":"Fred", "ADDRESS":"Flat1", "AGE": 92, "GENDER":"M"}

2014-05-15,14:36:26,subject,{"MSGTYPE":"Personal", "NAME":"George", "ADDRESS":"Flat2", "AGE": -20, "GENDER":"M"}

2014-05-13,16:49:26,subject,{"MSGTYPE":"Personal", "NAME":"Ringo", "ADDRESS":"Flat3", "AGE": -36, "GENDER":"M"}

2014-05-12,14:45:26,subject,{"MSGTYPE":"Personal", "NAME":"Brian", "ADDRESS":"Flat4", "AGE": -85, "GENDER":"M"}

2014-05-11,12:43:26,subject,{"MSGTYPE":"Personal", "NAME":"Paul", "ADDRESS":"Flat5", "AGE": -33, "GENDER":"M"}
```

it would work like this:

```
import json
fname = "data.txt"
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) == 0:
            continue
        if line.startswith('**Records**'):
            continue
        valuesArray = line.split(',', 3)
        y, d = valuesArray[:2]
        print '1: {y}'.format(y=y)
        print '2: {d}'.format(d=d)    
        # bonus, read the json data
        print valuesArray[3]

        jsdata = json.loads(valuesArray[3])
        print "jsdata", jsdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Should  `print '2: {1}'.format(valuesArray[1])` not be  
       `print '2: {0}'.format(valuesArray[1])`?

There is only one argument in the formatting, index 1 is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is on your second `format` line:

```
print '2: {1}'.format(valuesArray[1])
```

You are only formatting one value, so the `{1}` should be `{0}`

The proper use of `{1}` would be if you had something like this:

```
print "1: {0} {1}".format(valuesArray[0], valuesArray[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is the case that your real input file has blank lines between the records like your example has, then that would probably explain why your split does not produce any values. Also, be aware that `line` will contain a trailing newline character, so you may want to call `line.strip()` inside your loop.